# Notation - d.o.f.'s for Grassmann delta functions in a SUSY field theory amplitude

Tags: notation, representation-theory, supersymmetry, dirac-delta-distributions, grassmann-numbers

I was reading the following paper

https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2962

as I stumbled upon an issue concerning counting and assigning the Grassmann degrees of freedom that appear in grassmann delta functions and which are integrated over.

Let's first introduce the picture by describing the part which makes sense to me. In equation (1.3) a general expression for an $n$-particle amplitude in certain theories is given, which involves Grassmann delta functions $\delta^{0|\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}}(\langle\lambda_a \theta^I_a\rangle)$ and $\delta^{0|\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}}(\langle\tilde\lambda_a \tilde\theta^I_a\rangle)$. Here the superscript "$0|\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$" is clear. It denotes that the delta function holds $0$ bosonic subfunctions and $\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$ fermionic (grassmann) subfunctions. The number $\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$ here is also clear, since in the previous paragraph the authors point out that they use a representation of $SU(\mathcal{N})$ that is projected onto $SU(\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2})\times SU(\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2})$, which makes the index $I$ on the grassmann variables $\theta^I,\tilde\theta^I$ run through $I=1,2,...,\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$.

So far so good, however, in equation (1.5) the authors reshape the amplitude expression somewhat and dress it with more delta functions and integrals. Now, here the two Grassmann delta functions each obtain $\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$ fermionic subfunctions more and now read $\delta^{0|\mathcal{N}}(...)$. And this is where my confusion with the notation sets in. Since the chosen representation allows the R-charge index $I$ to run only over $I=1,2,...,\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$ (for both $SU(\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2})$ factors), it is not clear to me which index should be assigned to the sub-delta-functions in $\delta^{0|\mathcal{N}}(\theta_a...)$ and $\delta^{0|\mathcal{N}}(\tilde\theta_a...)$  that are associated with numbers $\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}+1,...,\mathcal{N}$. Do the authors mean to imply that the indices simply loop back and repeat the numbers $1,2,...,\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$ once they cross $\frac{\mathcal{N}}{2}$? Do they mean something else? It would be great if someone could clarify this.